# Two RewriteRules - one Match

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a really simple Problem, but couldn't find the answer...

The website Base is /home/

```
RewriteEngine On
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
RewriteBase /home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home
RewriteRule ^(/?)(.*) /home/$2 [L]
```

1. ) Url /home/docs/news works fine, but /home/docs/news/page1/ will  not be rewritten - Why?
2. ) What should i add now, to get /home/docs/ also rewritten to / ?

Thanks a lot,
tried so much.

Leola

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser for testing and what error are you getting?

Comment: /home/docs/news/page1/ -> This is the url i entering in my browser

Comment: Ok, if i write the links in html, they works fine, must be something within the php script (was not my work). The browser renders the links correct ( /docs/news/page1/) but if i click on it, the link in the address bar change to  /home/docs/news/page1/ 

Do you know how to update the htaccess to get /docs/ rewritten to / ? Urls should look like www.mydomain.com/news instead of www.mydomain.com/docs/news

Comment: You need to clarify your setup first. What is your DocumentRoot? Where is .htaccess located? Where are other files located etc?

Comment: Thanks for your great help,  

Webserver DocumentRoot was /, but now it's /home (with htaccess, works fine)   
Files are like this:
/home/index.php,   /home/other.php,   /home/docs/index.php,   /home/docs/news/index.php, /home/docs/news/page1/index.php  - If you could help me to rewrite this, it would be great. The errors in the php scripts i will find myself,

Comment: And you just want to remove `docs` from URL?

Comment: Yes, but didn't get it done, because of my first rewrite

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question?

Comment: Have updated my question

Comment: Is this .htaccess placed in `/home` directory or at a level above?

Comment: In /, a level above: /.htaccess, /home/index.php and so on

Answer (score 0):

Place this .htaccess in `/home/docs/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/docs/

RewriteRule ^((?!docs/).*)$ docs/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: http://www.mydomain.at/news/ ends up with 404 (The requested URL /home/news/ was not found on this server.)